# API that gives owner of tx/address?

Tags: address, ownership

I'm trying to do some analysis of different entities on the bitcoin network. I'm looking for an API that I can input a transaction id or address into and it will tell me the exchange, miner, or other entity that it is most likely connected with.

Blockchain.info, for example, has [tags](https://blockchain.info/tags) that are visible when you search for an address, for example those associated with Mt. Gox. However, it doesn't seem like this is available through their API.

There are other sites out there like http://bitcoinwhoswho.com, but haven't found a simple API yet.

This must be out there somewhere. Can someone point me in the right direction?